# Converting laser_scan_matcher demo to use hokuyo node input

Tags: ros, scan, hokuyo-node, hokuyo, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a hokuyo Lidar compatible with hokuyo_node package and can run it fine.  And, I've also run the default laser_scan_matcher demo executed from roslaunch.

My goal is to see the same demo but using live laser scan messages.  I'm new to ROS so I'm sure I'm missing something.

I've taken the default demo.launch file and cut out the rosbag part and started a hokuyo_node instead, but I don't appear to see anything the rvis.  I've used rxgraph to compare the to and the only piece I don't understand is the purpose and necessity of the "clock" topic from rosbag to laser_scan_matcher. It's not mentioned in the scarce documentation.

Would someone please offer direction on how to substitude the laser scans from rosbag to a hokuyo_node.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11095/converting-laser_scan_matcher-demo-to-use-hokuyo-node-input/) by [Tim C](https://answers.ros.org/users/1028/tim-c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jister](https://answers.ros.org/users/22529/jister/) on 2015-05-23**:
Hi, I also have the same question, have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a launch file that should work:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node"/>
  
  <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node"
    name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
  </node>
  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser"
    args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 40" />
   
</launch>
```

The first node launches the `hokuyo_node` driver, the second one launches the `laser_scan_matcher`, and the third one provides the neccessary tf from the `base_link` to the `laser` frame.

The parameters in the laser_scan_matcher aren't required, but tweaking them will probably improve performance. Check the documentation to see what the parameter options are and to find out what works best for you.

**EDIT**

The clock parameter is documented [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#play).

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be a problem with timestamps, try setting this parameter to false ([clock documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock))

```
 <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>
```

Anyway you should check the [laser_scan_matcher documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher) to see if there are any other parameters you have to change (for example the topic's name or frame names). 
If so, you have to add them into the laser_scan_matcher call. ([launch documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML))

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1